# Спарсить кнопку через jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Всем привет! Как через jsoup спарсить кнопку "загрузить еще"? Есть блог в котором показывается 10 постов, чтобы загрузить еще нужно нажать на кнопку, как ее спарсить или обойти эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `jsoup` нельзя нажать на кнопку, можно только получить текст элемента. Если необходимо автоматизировать работу с браузером, то используйте `Selenium Webdriver`.

Если можно ограничиться получением текста элемента, то есть хорошее объяснение как это сделать [здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2007-legkiy-parsing-html-s-pomojshjhju-jsoup) и [здесь](https://o7planning.org/ru/10399/jsoup-java-html-parser-tutorial).